# How can I use imperial units when entering measurements?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, units

I've set my units (`UnitSettings.system`) to *Imperial* in **Properties** → **Scene** → **Units**. I can now see my measurements in imperial units. For example, I see that the Z-gravity is set to -32.185 ft/s<sup>2</sup>.

However, when I enter any units into an operator, the default (metric) units are used, and everything is 3.28× greater than it should be. For example, selecting a cube and pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> causes the cube to move 3′ 3.4″ along the X axis. Before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the transform, I can see that the status bar reads:

> D: 1 | (3' 3.4") along global X

Is there a way to configure Blender so that when I press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, it actually moves it one foot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is now supported, as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB87cc890aef53c4660448b1125dc0c40a187ae1f2) (it's [in 2.70](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI/#Transform_Tools_Number_Input)).

To use this:

1. Start the modal transform operator (grab, rotate, etc.)
2. Press <kbd>=</kbd> to enter advanced mode
3. Enter the value you want according to the units you have selected (e.g. for imperial: `4' 11'`)

When in advanced mode you can do everything you can do in a normal number button:

[image]

If you don't press <kbd>=</kbd> to enter advanced mode, it should behave mostly as it did before 2.70.

From [the wiki](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI/#Transform_Tools_Number_Input):

> We have two "modes", simple and advanced ones, use '=' or 'pad*' to
>   enable advanced mode, and 'ctrl-=' or 'ctrl-pad*' to switch back to
>   simple mode.
>
> Simple mode works nearly like it did before, it only accepts simple
>   numbers, and you can still use '-' to negate and '/' to inverse the
>   value (as well as non-number input shortcuts like XYZ, RSG, etc.).
>   Compared to Blender 2.69 behavior, you can now copy and paste
>   expressions, and navigate in the number you typed, so you can for
>   example fix a typo without having to type everything again.
>
> In advanced mode, we gain more power and flexibility, but lose a few
>   "shortcuts" like '-' to negate, or '/' to inverse. It features:
>
> - Units (cm, ", deg, etc.).
> - Basic operations from python/BKE_unit (+, *, **, etc.), and math constants and functions (pi, sin, etc.).
> - You can navigate in edited value (left/right key, ctrl to move by block) and insert/delete chars, e.g. to fix a typo without having to
>     rewrite everything.
> - You can copy/paste expression with usual ctrl-C/V.
> - You can go to next/previous value with (ctrl-)TAB key.
> - As before, hitting backspace after having deleted all leading chars will first reset the edited value to init state, and on second
>     press, the whole number editing will be canceled, going back to usual
>     transform with mouse.
> - You can still use the - and / shortcuts, as well as various transform options (like XYZ, E and F for vertex/edge slide, etc.)
>     while in modal numinput mode, you just have to use ctrl to activate
>     them!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much! So that's why editing changed... backspace doesn't clear the whole thing anymore, `-` doesn't negate, etc. I like the idea of new shortcuts for numinput mode.

Comment: @WChargin It should behave as before if you don't press `=` to enable advanced mode. (The reason advanced mode exists is because there was a bit of an uproar when pressing `-` after entering a value didn't negate it)..

Comment: The wiki was moved, now it's https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI/#Transform_Tools_Number_Input

Comment: @sergk Thanks, updated

Answer (score 5):

You can Type **Feet & Inches** or **(1' 2") Notation** in **Transform : Location** Field/Slider to precisely move your mesh. It is just like working in 3dsmax, where you type in the desired numbers for precise movement.
[image]

In the screen shot, i have precisely moved my box by typing **1 feet 4 inch** in Location X : Field/Slider.
The distance is calculated from the Pivot of the mesh.
A Solid Understanding of the Blender Unit System is available at this link
[Metric & Blender Units in Blender](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/metric-imperial-units.php)

Comment: I'm aware of this. However, this limits me to only using the property adjusters to manipulate my objects - and, even worse, vertices.

Answer (score 0):

1 Blender unit is equivalent to, in imperial measurements, 3 feet, or, with the metric system, 1 meter. Due to the fact that the makers of Blender come from Europe, this is the system of measurement they are accustomed to. So in order to get 1 ft. you will want to use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>`.3`</kbd>.

Comment: It's not exactly one foot though. It's 11.81102 inches.

Comment: not exactly, but for practical purposes it is close enough. Off by what? .4

Comment: It's off by more than 1.5%. This is more than enough to allow tolerance errors.

Comment: So what .02 inches? Maybe in blender that is a big deal but as far as actuall building is concerned then .02 inches off is not that big a deal, and barely perceptable. You would have to zoom in on blender to see that small of an error. But this is your question, so It is a mute point anyway. Believe what you want

Comment: (1) It's not 0.02 inches, it's 0.20 inches. That's a difference in itself. (2) There are many cases where this matters. For example, an engine piston can have tolerances of anywhere from 0.004 inches to [0.0002 inches](http://www.daypiston.com/precision-cnc-machining-pistons.html) - 50 to 1000 times the error induced by this method. Or, consider a sliding drawer that couldn't fit in a hole. Or, consider a hallway that's illegal because it's three inches too short and isn't sufficiently accessible for the disabled. These are just a few examples.

Comment: Ok point taken. As I said it is a mute point. I don't wish to waste my time argueing with some one over something as unimportant as this. You seem to know what you are talking about, and that is satisfying enough. Btw 2% of 1 inch is .02 inches. If I know anything it is math. .2 inches is 20 %