# How do you set the scale for a specific project?

Tags: modeling, measurement

For my current project, I've decided to use metric units. I am trying to work at the millimeter level, but when I create a new object (Cube) it's set to a one meter scale by default. How do I tell Blender that I want the default scale for all new objects in this blend file to be set to, for instance, one centimeter?

When using the Blender units scale I didn't concern myself with this stuff, but I'm trying to be more accurate in my designs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set units and scale in the Properties Panel

[image]

Newly added cube after scaling to .01m with *Edge Info Length* enabled:

[image]

There are also a few settings in 3D-Views Properties-Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) these influence only the display:

[image]

See also:

- [How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements)
- [How can I use imperial units when entering measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/how-can-i-use-imperial-units-when-entering-measurements/2315#2315)

Comment: Thanks!  That setting had escaped me.  I kept looking in UserPref thinking it would be there but I guess this makes more sense