# Where can I find the diameter of my object?

Tags: import

I imported a file of a globe into Blender and would like to 3d print it on a friends printer.  I would like it to resize it so that I can send him the file, and the globe will be 2.5 inches in diameter when printed.  O can't find out where that info is though.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/how-do-you-set-the-scale-for-a-specific-project; also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254/how-do-blender-units-and-meters-feet-or-yards-correlate

Answer (score 1):

You can change units scall into the scene menu:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

[image: Scene > Units]

Choose a one system from Metric and Imperial. You can check mark "Separate Units" to change how the values are shown. Use "Scale" to make the whole world bigger or smaller.

[image: units]