# How to set a specific edge length numerically?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I've got this question from one of my best students. The question is the following:

Suppose, that we have *Edit mode* with some edges, vertices, etc. How to set a selected edge to have a specific length? Numerically?

We already know, that scaling with enabled *'Show edge length'* is helpful, but in general, it seems to be easier to just select an edge, and to set its length. This is extremely useful for architecture modeling.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68678/28015

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**This feature is now in an included addon in Blender 2.79** called *Mesh: Edit Tools 2*. You have to enable the addon in the User Preferences.

[image: User Preferences...]

1. Go to Add-ons
2. Search "edit"
3. Click the box for Mesh: Edit Tools 2
4. Save User Settings

[image: Enable Mesh: Edit Tools 2]

While in Edit Mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> for the Specials Menu

- *Edit Tools > Set Edge Length*
- Input a target length and click OK.[image: Resize Edge]

Hope this helps! I searched forever to find the answer. Shoutout to Danyang Yi for providing the link to a previous version of this addon prior to it being included in Blender.

Comment: This is fantastic, and just what I was looking for! Thank you Doug. For those using Blender 2.8, you will find the option in the "N" panel > Edit > Edge Tools > Set Edge Length.

Answer (score 11):

A quick and dirty way is to type in the number like this `"{target_length} / {current_length}"`. For example, if you want to scale the length of an edge from `1.176` to `4`, you can switch the Transformation mode to *Normal*, then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, type in `4/1.176` for a certain axis, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

**P.S.:** It won't be accurate since the Mesh Display is not so accurate. You need a small script or addon to get the easier and more accurate calculation. I suggest to use the integrated Ruler/Protractor tool. It can save an numeral value with 8 decimal places if you copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) it. (Tip: The snap feature for the ruler only works well with Wireframe mode, currently.)

[image]

There is also another question that collects some good ways to do so. [How to get selected edges length?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1674/696)

Comment: Your post makes no sense if you don't explain how to navigate through the menu. I was unable to follow this.

Answer (score 9):

It's seems you guys will like this [addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?335568-Addon-Directly-Set-Length%28edge%29-and-Angle%28edges%29-v0-2).

[image]

*Toolbar > Tools > Mesh Tools > edges set*.

- Set Length: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
- Set Angle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

I found probably the easiest and most obvious way to do this in Blender 2.9.

Activate the shipped add-on *Mesh Tools*, and in Edit Mode, go to <kbd>N</kbd> menu  *Edit > Edge Tools > Set Edge Length*

[image: Set Edge Length option in Blender 2.93.4]

Answer (score 5):

One way to set the length of an edge is:

- Select the edge in edit mode
- Scale to size 1 <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Numpad /</kbd>current edge length<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Scale again to the desired length in blender units say 2.5 <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2.5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

An easier way would be to extrude the edges from a single vertext from the start.

- Select vertext (Edit mode; vertext select)
- <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X,Y or Z</kbd>desired length<kbd>Enter</kbd>

For architecture modelling there is also an addon called [archimesh](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?315980-Archimesh-Architecture-elements-(rooms-doors-columns-stairs-tile-roofs)).

Other related questions:

- [How do blender units and meters, feet, or yards correlate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254/how-do-blender-units-and-meters-feet-or-yards-correlate/258#258)
- [How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements)
- [How can I use imperial units when entering measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/how-can-i-use-imperial-units-when-entering-measurements)

Answer (score 3):

Clunky and bait for floating point shenanigans.. but it works:

- From <kbd>N</kbd> menu, show Edge Length.
- In Edit Mode using vertex select, choose the vertex you want to keep where it is, then move 3D cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>)
- In edge select mode, select the edge
- Hit main keyboard (not numpad) Full Stop/Period (<kbd>.</kbd>) to set 3D cursor as scale/rotate pivot
- Hit <kbd>S</kbd>, type the current length of the edge and hit <kbd>/</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this will scale it to 1 unit exactly (`/` toggles whether the scale amount entered is inverse)
- Hit <kbd>S</kbd> again, type the length you want the edge to be in Blender units and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to create a trapezoid with top edge 50 cm and bottom 100 cm.

The easiest way I've found is to:
 1. create a "Helper" plane mesh
 2. (Press N to show the right panel if not seen.) in the Transform section under Dimensions set it's desire axis to the exact length. In my case I've set the Y axis to be 50cm.
 3. Select the real object (your mesh) and enter edit mode (Tab).
 4. At the bottom panel toggle "Magnet" on and choose "Vertex" and "Closest".
5. Now drag (G) the desired vertex to the "Helper" object. The magnet will make sure you do it correctly. After you dragged the 2 vertexes to the correct "Helper" vertexes exit edit mode.
6. Repeat from step 2- in my case I changed it's size to 100 cm and then adjusted the relevant bottom vertexes.

Hope this help, If not say so And I can maybe upload instructions with pictures