# How do you set dimension between edges?

Tags: modeling

On the cube when I split it to form blocks, how do you set the length and width of the split?

Comment: The answer will depend on the method you use to split the cube. Do you use the Subdivide tool or something else?

Comment: In the properties panel (N) under mesh display you can show edge length which can help if your using loop cut. [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically) and [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements) might also help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by split? by my understanding there is no tool called split. how are you going about splitting said cube? are you using loop cut? are you subdividing? are you using the bisect tool? the options available depend entirely on the method you are using.. and the idea of blender is to have more than one way to accomplish the same task (funny that python was developed as a language intended to have "one ,and preferably only one", obvious way to accomplish you task)