# How display and execute in the right context UI elements of operator in a panel?

Tags: python, properties, operator

In reference to my other question, i try to display my properties operator directly in the UI Panel, but when i "click" on the created buttons and field, nothing happens.

For my tow parameters `"axis"` and `"newdim"` :

The action takes place here: `bpy.context.object.axis = y`

The action takes place here: `bpy.context.object.newdim = 2.5`

where i need it takes place like this:

```
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 2.5
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 'y'
bpy.ops.object.resize_proportional(axis='y', newdim=2.5)
```

So, change value have no effect.
How can i have this panel presentation in UI (like the script bellow), with direcly choice between X, Y and Z, and directly de width value adjustable, and above all this to take effect ?

```
from bpy import *
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, EnumProperty

#————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————#
    # The Resize Operator
#————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————#
class ResizeProportional(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.resize_proportional"
    bl_label = "Choose_the_Right_Axis"
    bl_description = "This is to choose the axis"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    axis = EnumProperty(
            name="Axis",
            description="Axis selection",
            items= [('x', "X", ""),('y', "Y", ""),('z', "Z","")],
            default='x'
            )

    newdim = FloatProperty(
            name="Width",
            description="Scale",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=1,
            )

    # The Resize function
    #———————————————————————————————————#
    def scale(self, axis, new_dim):
        ob = bpy.context.active_object
        d = ob.dimensions

        x = d[0]
        y = d[1]
        z = d[2]

        scale =  axis

        if( scale == "x"):
            indice = 0
        elif( scale == "y"):
            indice = 1
        else:
            indice = 2

        old_dim = d[indice] 
        factor = new_dim / old_dim

        scale_x = ob.scale[0]
        scale_y = ob.scale[1]
        scale_z = ob.scale[2]

        ob.scale[0] = scale_x * factor
        ob.scale[1] = scale_y * factor
        ob.scale[2] = scale_z * factor

#    def invoke(self, context, event):
#        wm = context.window_manager
#        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.scale(self.axis,self.newdim)
        return {'FINISHED'}

#————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————#
    # The Proportional Dimensions Panel
#————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————#
class ProportionalDimensions(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object UI window"""
    bl_label = "Proportional Dimensions"
    bl_idname = "prop_dim"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    #bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        layout.prop(obj, "my_global_axis", expand=True)
        layout.prop(obj, "my_global_newdim")

        #props = layout.operator(ResizeProportional.bl_idname)
        #props.axis = obj.my_global_axis

        #layout = self.layout
        #layout.operator(ResizeProportional.bl_idname, text ="Resize active object: "+ obj.name)

#————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————#

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ProportionalDimensions)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ResizeProportional)

    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.Object.my_global_axis = EnumProperty(
        name="Axis",
        description="Axis selection",
        items= [('x', "X", ""),('y', "Y", ""),('z', "Z","")],
        default='x'
    )

    bpy.types.Object.my_global_newdim = FloatProperty(
        name="Width",
        description="Scale",
        min=0.01, max=100.0,
        default=1,
    )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ProportionalDimensions)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ResizeProportional)

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    del bpy.types.Object.axis
    del bpy.types.Object.newdim

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Is this question primarily about how to resize proportionally? I don't see a reason why you would want to implement that, there are already multiple built-in ways to do that - `S` to scale (with optional keyboard input) and [multi-number editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Multi-Number_Button_Editing). To do something alike with Python, I would probably use a property with callback, but it's a bit tricky to not create infinite loops.

Comment: There is no tools, and no ways to do this. Exemple : you make a bottle to a exact size like 1 unit = 1 cm (for exemple). You bottle messure x: 6,8 cm, and y: 3,2 cm. Your client want to change this after to x: 4,36 (again for exemple), but you must keep exactly the proportions of the bottle created. So, how could you do that ? you can't, in blender you juste can't. the scale is approximative and you can't specify an exact measure. With this tool, you can.

Comment: 4.36cm / 6.8cm = ~0.6412, select the bottle, hit `S` and type `0.6412` to rescale to exact dimensions while keeping proportions. If you want to make this a tool that automatically uses e.g. the bounding box dimensions of either of the 3 axes, I would use a props dialog. Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically (but note that proportions are not kept if you edit a single scale property).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple workflow to resize an object, without the need to code any new tools.

Going from your comments I will be resizing a bottle. First open the Properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd>.
In object mode simply type the new dimension for any of the three axes in to the proper *Dimensions* field in the properties panel.
The Next step is to copy the new scale value to the other two axes. Simply hover over the changed scale field and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then hover over the two unscaled axis and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
Last (if you want the object's scale set to one) apply the new scale with <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*, or in the 3D view header *Object > Apply > Scale*.

You now have a resized object with the exact same portions as the original.

[image: bottle to resize with properties panel open] [image: bottle after changing a dimension for one of the axes]