# Can the scale tool show me the real size of the object instead of a 1 - 0 scale?

Tags: transforms, units, measurement

when I resize I want to see the real width\length\dept of the object instead of the x=1 y=1 z=1.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18941/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the *Dimensions* in *3D view > Tool shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>)?

[image]

You can also [change the units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254/599) these values are represented in. By default they are displayed in "blender units" (BU), which are equal to meters. To do this, adjust the settings in *Properties > Scene > Units*:

[image]

---

I should also point out that the *Scale* of an object is not limited to 0-1. For example:

- A scale of 1 = no distortion
- A scale of 2 = twice as large
- A scale of -1 = [inverted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1093/599)

The [*Scale*](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/scale.html) object property is really factor by which you can non-destructively shrink or stretch the object in any given axis without modifying the mesh.

It's useful to know this, as it can result in some [unexpected results](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28248/599) if you are unaware of what scale is actually doing. See [my answer here for more detail](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12288/599).

Answer (score 3):

No, the three numbers you are talking about in the 3D view header, while you are scaling an object, is the scale factor (example cube is 2" scale factor of 1.5, the cube is now 3").

If you want to change a object by typing in the dimensions you can do so in object mode in the properties region, explained in [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24215/2217).

The process is

1. change one of the dimensions
   [image: bottle after changing a dimension for one of the axes]
2. copy the new scale from that channel to the other two.
3. apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want units like meters or inch, you can go to the properties panel, then to scene and then to the tab units. Here you can choose metric or imperial. The dimensions is in meters or inches.

[image]