# Is there a way to do absolute measurements in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, scale, measurement

What I'm trying to accomplish is something as simple as grabbing a line or two verts (maybe more complex objects if possible) within edit mode and then setting their scale to an absolute measurement.

In my example I'm building a wall and want to cut out a window. Say I have a simple plane for a wall and I cut some slices through it so I have a square of verts in the middle. I could technically grab say the two top verts of the window frame and just hit S then move the mouse to where I want it, but that would never be 100% accurate. I just want to be able to hit S then type 2 to make it 2 units between the two verts instead of double the space between them. Is there a way to use absolute numbers instead of relative ones inside edit mode?

I know it's possible to do this in object mode, but in my example that would mean cutting the square out, duplicating the object, deleting all but the window frame, resizing, applying scale, combining the objects again, then welding. And that would only work if the window was completely axis aligned. Then doing that for every time I need a specific measurement for a whole scene.

There has to be a better way to model things to specific measurements. Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically

Comment: You ever get an answer to this Austin?