# How to set a specific distance between two vertices?

Tags: units, measurement

I'm on Blender 2.79 and could not figure out how to set distances between vertices(or anything) in Blender. I'd like the distance between the two selected points in this image to be 77cm or in my .blend file 0.77 Blender units.

[image: 2 points]

I can measure this distance with the protractor and move the two vertices, but if I'm just moving them by hand it will never be exact. I want to be able to enter a number in a box somewhere, and it to be the distance between them. How do I do this? This seems to me like one of the most basic features of any 3D design program, but I can't find an answer on the interwebs.

Comment: I guess you can find some answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically

Comment: This add-on does what you ask. https://github.com/Storme9/vertex_insert

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can slide (<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>)the vertex down to the bottom corner, and then <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> and '0.77' to move it back again.

In general, when things aren't nicely lined up,

- With snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active',
- First create a Custom Orientation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) from the edge you want to measure down (or parallel to).
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate any vertex to make one you can use as a snapping source/target.
- Snap your new loose vertex to a starting point
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>+(numerical entry) your vertex parallel to your Custom orientation.

you now have a measured point to snap other things to.

I use a lot of Custom Orientations, so I check 'Use after Creation' and 'Overwrite Previous' in the Tool Shelf.

Using Custom Orientations and a loose vertex, with the pivot set to 'Active Element', you can extend this method to measure angles around an axis in the custom edge's direction, through the active element (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>+(numerical entry))