# Blender 2.8 edge length

Tags: interface, edges

I'm new to blender and I want to use it as 3D printing software. I'm using 2.8 so I'll get used to new interface, but I don't know how to change edge length to a specific value. I know how to change whole object dimensions like cube, I'm using metric system and I can see edge length when selected, but how do I change it?

Answer (score 3):

I found this addon and updated to 2.8. I think this is what you're wanting.

[Addon located here](https://blenderartists.org/t/edge-resizer-operator/634873/5)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not at my computer right now, so cannot confirm, but Blender internal addons should have been properly ported to 2.80, so I believe the "Mesh: Edit Tools 2" trick should still work:     [How to set a specific edge length numerically?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically) have you tried that?

Comment: I know how to scale and such, I've watched tutorials, but I want to determine the SPECIFIC value to existing edge I mean for example 130mm. Also I tried to find the answer for that already but every explanation relate to previous versions. I even tried to search official manual and I could't find anything since it is incomplete "Todo" or refers to earlier builds of beta (or maybe even I don't know how to find it).

Comment: I found that too but there is no "Mesh: Edit Tools 2" in 2.8. I got it working through add-on AFWS got.