# Is it possible to resize faces/edges/vertices to a specific size?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have some previous experience from both Hexagon and 3DS Max. And you can easily resize a face, edge or a group of vertices to a precise number in both platforms. For example, you can create a 2x2x2 m box, then select one single side (face) and set the size to 2.189 m. For example.

Blender does have a size pane. But only for entire objects. I can set the width of an entire object to 2.189. But not a single face. Or an edge. In order to do the operation above in Blender I'd have to bring out a calculator and figure out the ratio of 2.000 to 2.189 and punch in that number in the resize tool. I can't for the life of me understand why there's no built in size panel for stuff like this.

What also bugs me is that for the very same reason you cannot easily read the size of an element, such as a face or an edge. Sure, there is a distance tool. But a lot of time I'd like to know the size in X, Y and Z. Not the actual distance from one end of an edge to the other.

Is there some plugin or setting in Blender for this? I basically want to be able to select a face or an edge, and see the size in all three directions. And also be able to change the size by punching in numbers. Resizing the width of an edge from, let's say 3.448 to 3.207 shouldn't require a calculator.

Comment: Related: [How can i set a specific length for an edge?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161528/78972)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 edge length](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128021/blender-2-8-edge-length)

Comment: There's always an option to press **S**, left click, expand the popup in bottom left, and type <new dimension> / <old dimension> as the scale. Or **S**, then **/**, then current dimension, to get a dimension of **1**, then **S** and type/paste the desired dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately, I think the best you can do for now is to enable face and edge measurements under overlays. It's only a display - it doesn't let you input any numbers directly, but at least it lets you see dimensions as you scale, and transform and whatnot. If an add-on for this type of thing does exist, I would love if someone could point it out. Until then, I think this is what we're stuck with.

[image: Measurements]

Comment: CAD Transform for Blender may help?