# How can i set a specific length for an edge?

Tags: add-on

I want to build a room with specific length. For example 40cm. So, i want to put a specific value somewhere. Answer only for Blender 2.8/ 2.81 pls. BTW sorry for my bad english

Comment: Related, but don't know if it works for 2.8: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically

Comment: I already tried that, but Edit Tools doesen't appear when im pressing w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to illustrate Ray's comment.

Enable **✓** the Mesh Tools addon.
*Preferences > Addons > Edit Mesh Tools*
[image]

Switch to *Edit mode*, to see the Mesh Tools addon.
It's under *Sidebar > Edit > Mesh Tools*

[image]