# Why Scaling and Dimension don't align

Tags: scale

I've created a kind of a planter using curves (this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAAnpRR2ILg)

My initial object was very small - matching my base measurements of 1mm, so I wanted to scale it up:

1. I couldn't find how to exactly scale it in edit mode: in the n-menu
   I see nothing mentioning "dimensions". Also in "Object Properties" - I can't find the way to scale the dimensions.
2. So I manually scaled it in edit mode and later made it more exact in object mode.
3. This changed the scale - I can't say I understand how all that scaling and changing dimensions work :-(.

Now when I set the right dimensions in the n-menu in object mode and later fix the scale with CTRL+A => the dimensions "overshoot" and when I fix them, the scale undershoots - somehow I can't get the right measures in 1:1:1 scale.

Can anyone please help? - **what is the CORRECT way to EXACTLY size an object?**

just for reference: I want an object 120X120X140 mm (XYZ) in size

Here is the file: [image]

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: In Properties sidebar (N) set Dimension as needed and Apply Scale (Ctrl+A) should work, but if you have problems probably object is parented to another one. I didn't check link to much. Would be faster if you can attach blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to check. Thanks

Comment: OK I check the link, I would suggest use screw modifier on profile curve object. Like that you don't need to use path object and previous comment should work for you.

Comment: to understand the difference between scaling in edit mode or object mode read: [why do the measurements seem erroneous](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous)

Comment: @vklidu I've added the file - you will see it has a path (diameter I never change) and a profile I use for changing the size and shape of the planter (it's still work in progress...)

Comment: Sorry, Im on vacation now, so i cant check the file, but as i said I think your issue is in relationship path-profile. If nobody is going to explain to you, try the Screw modifier instead of the path. With origin in center of expected  final object lets modifier rotate profile. Than you can set dimension in object mode without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case - **Curve Profile on Circular Path**

### Circle Path

You use Bevel parameter in curve properties to shape curve object (Path). Shape (bevel) is defined by Profile object to generate final object. In this technique profile object follows path object positioned by Profile object's origin.

If circle path represents final size

- set dimension of circle 120x120
- apply *Scale* Ctrl+A

### Profile Curve

- create half cut of your object - profile.
- for final object dimension 120x120x140 (XYZ) set profile 60x140x0
- apply *Scale* Ctrl+A

Important think here is position of curve profile against its origin in edit mode (doesnt matter where object is placed in space). Also better to work with 2D curve (instead of 3D).

For your circle path you have two options how to position profile curve against the origin.

- 1st - place curve with the most outer part to origin (so you dont have to set offset later)
- 2nd - place curve as origin represents center of final object

Here is second version - origin as center of final object, so it is more natural to see and imagine result. If you rotate Profile object in X 90 it will follow final shape.

[image]

Now just select Circle Path object and under *Properties Editor - Geometry - Bevel* choose *Profile* object and **Offset -60**

[image]

---

### Screw Modifier (alternative way)

My personal suggestion is to use **Screw Modifier** for Profile object directly rather than tutorial you follow.

Just select Profile object you adjusted in previous verion and ad Screw Modifier. Increase **Steps** for more smooth result or use Subsurf Modifier.

[image]

---

Both examples
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For precise scaling, consider using Orthographic View and grid snapping.

1. Enable *View > Orthographic View* (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>), and then choose one of views, Shortcut: <kbd>~</kbd>
2. Enable *Snapping > Increment*, and check *Absolute snap*. This will ensure snapping to grid.
3. The grid will scale when you zoom in and out

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @jachym-michal. 1. Just a general question: what app are you using to capture your screen? 2. so I must make sure my scale is 1:1:1 in object mode and make all the dimension changes only in edit mode? 3. I've done as you instructed and it worked BUT - isn't there a more humane way of doing that? why can't I numerically change the size of an object and need to drag-to-size?

Comment: In order :). 1. [Licecap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) 2. That's just my way :) [Why do measurements seem wrong?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47318/78972) 3. [How to set edge length numerically?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4890/78972)