How do you edit the dimension of an edge?
How do you edit the dimension of an edge without effecting the rest of the object?  I have tried the properties tab in Object Mode but that only effects the overall dimensions.  For example, if I have an object with an appendage that I want to be longer changing the axis dimension effects more than the appendage.

hello you have some answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-to-set-a-specific-edge-length-numerically
