# How do I change Blender's dimensions to display in inches?

Tags: units, dimensions

I'm am trying to scale an object but the dimensions are "m"?  Is that "meter"?  Too big for my printer.  I'd like to change it to inches.  Is there a setting for that?

Comment: Related: [How can I use imperial units when entering measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/how-can-i-use-imperial-units-when-entering-measurements)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, *m* stands for meters. You can change the units in the *Scene Properties* tab.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks.  These models I'm looking at are much bigger than I thought.

Comment: @3DHarry Please consider marking the answer as accepted ✓ :). Thank you.