# Can't switch from metric to imperial units

Tags: interface, units

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to switch units from the default metric to imperial. I go to Scene => Units => Unit System and change it to metric, but after I edit anything, everything switches back to metric. For example, I change a dimension to x feet, but once I press enter, the value changes to the equivalent in meters. Is there a way to change the unit system permanently, or am I overlooking something?

After looking around for answers, I found something about [advanced mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/how-can-i-use-imperial-units-when-entering-measurements), but pressing the equal sign doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hello :). That's odd, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Perhaps restarting blender could help?

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks, restarting Blender fixed the issue. I should have tried that earlier.